# Prepend in WordPress/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, prepend

I'm trying to prepend some content above an input form on my WordPress site using jQuery. I can get it to prepend, but then I can't style it because I'm not able to add a class or

tags with the code I'm using. I want to be able to prepend the text, then style it etc. Note: there is also some space that prepends with the text, so I'd like to be able to remove that as well.

My code so far:

```
<script>
(function()
{
jQuery('#frm_field_conf_87_container').prepend("* Confirm Email Address");
})();
</script>
```

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help!

What I'm seeing:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rFRQ.png)

Comment: This is somewhat confusing? You can't style text, if you want to style it wrap it in a span, simple as that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
jQuery('#frm_field_conf_87_container').prepend("<span class='your-class'>* Confirm Email Address</span>");
```

Just used a span for the example, but you can use anthing you need to.

Comment: That's beautiful. Thanks so much. I'll try this asap. I just couldn't figure out how to get an html element in there. Thanks again! :D